# how to change the coreUi logo in Free React.js Admin Template of sidebar and header?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, customization, core-ui

First time , I am using **Free coreUi React.js Admin Template**.

where I am trying to change the the Header and sidebar Logo but I am unable understand the how to change it.

File Path: `src\containers\TheSidebar.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import {
  CCreateElement,
  CSidebar,
  CSidebarBrand,
  CSidebarNav,
  CSidebarNavDivider,
  CSidebarNavTitle,
  CSidebarMinimizer,
  CSidebarNavDropdown,
  CSidebarNavItem
} from "@coreui/react";

import CIcon from "@coreui/icons-react";

// sidebar nav config
import navigation from "./_nav";

const TheSidebar = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const show = useSelector(state => state.sidebarShow);

  return (
    <CSidebar
      show={show}
      onShowChange={val => dispatch({ type: "set", sidebarShow: val })}
    >
      <CSidebarBrand className="d-md-down-none" to="/">
        <CIcon
          className="c-sidebar-brand-full"
          name="logo-negative"

          height={35}
        />
        <CIcon
          className="c-sidebar-brand-minimized"
          name="sygnet"
          height={35}
        />
      </CSidebarBrand>
      <CSidebarNav>
        <CCreateElement
          items={navigation}
          components={{
            CSidebarNavDivider,
            CSidebarNavDropdown,
            CSidebarNavItem,
            CSidebarNavTitle
          }}
        />
      </CSidebarNav>
      <CSidebarMinimizer className="c-d-md-down-none" />
    </CSidebar>
  );
};

export default React.memo(TheSidebar);
```

File Path: `src\containers\TheHeader.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import {
  CHeader,
  CToggler,
  CHeaderBrand,
  CHeaderNav,
  CHeaderNavItem,
  CHeaderNavLink,
  CSubheader,
  CBreadcrumbRouter,
  CLink
} from "@coreui/react";
import CIcon from "@coreui/icons-react";

// routes config
import routes from "../routes";

import {
  TheHeaderDropdown,
  TheHeaderDropdownMssg,
  TheHeaderDropdownNotif,
  TheHeaderDropdownTasks
} from "./index";

const TheHeader = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const sidebarShow = useSelector(state => state.sidebarShow);

  const toggleSidebar = () => {
    const val = [true, "responsive"].includes(sidebarShow)
      ? false
      : "responsive";
    dispatch({ type: "set", sidebarShow: val });
  };

  const toggleSidebarMobile = () => {
    const val = [false, "responsive"].includes(sidebarShow)
      ? true
      : "responsive";
    dispatch({ type: "set", sidebarShow: val });
  };

  return (
    <CHeader withSubheader>
      <CToggler
        inHeader
        className="ml-md-3 d-lg-none"
        onClick={toggleSidebarMobile}
      />
      <CToggler
        inHeader
        className="ml-3 d-md-down-none"
        onClick={toggleSidebar}
      />
      <CHeaderBrand className="mx-auto d-lg-none" to="/">
        <CIcon name="logo"  height="48" alt="Logo" />
      </CHeaderBrand>

      <CHeaderNav className="d-md-down-none mr-auto">
        <CHeaderNavItem className="px-3">
          <CHeaderNavLink to="/dashboard">Dashboard</CHeaderNavLink>
        </CHeaderNavItem>
        <CHeaderNavItem className="px-3">
          <CHeaderNavLink to="/users">Users</CHeaderNavLink>
        </CHeaderNavItem>
        <CHeaderNavItem className="px-3">
          <CHeaderNavLink>Settings</CHeaderNavLink>
        </CHeaderNavItem>
      </CHeaderNav>

      <CHeaderNav className="px-3">
        <TheHeaderDropdownNotif />
        <TheHeaderDropdownTasks />
        <TheHeaderDropdownMssg />
        <TheHeaderDropdown />
      </CHeaderNav>

      <CSubheader className="px-3 justify-content-between">
        <CBreadcrumbRouter
          className="border-0 c-subheader-nav m-0 px-0 px-md-3"
          routes={routes}
        />
        <div className="d-md-down-none mfe-2 c-subheader-nav">
          <CLink className="c-subheader-nav-link" href="#">
            <CIcon name="cil-speech" alt="Settings" />
          </CLink>
          <CLink
            className="c-subheader-nav-link"
            aria-current="page"
            to="/dashboard"
          >
            <CIcon name="cil-graph" alt="Dashboard" />
            &nbsp;Dashboard
          </CLink>
          <CLink className="c-subheader-nav-link" href="#">
            <CIcon name="cil-settings" alt="Settings" />
            &nbsp;Settings
          </CLink>
        </div>
      </CSubheader>
    </CHeader>
  );
};

export default TheHeader;
```

these are above file where I am trying to change logo but unable to understand it. if any could help/ suggest to me then it will be the great help.

https://coreui.io/react/

[image: Header Logo]

[image: SideBar]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After digging into the code almost 2 days, I have found the easy solution.

1. First you can import logo in respective file as below:

**sidebar Logo changes:**

```
 src\containers\TheSidebar.js
```

a. import the file in above file  and add new property **SRC**

```
import logos from "../assets/logo.PNG";
```

b. pass the logos to **src** in `<CIcon>` component as props

```
 <CSidebarBrand className="d-md-down-none" to="/">
        <CIcon
          className="c-sidebar-brand-full"
          name="logo-negative"
          src={logos}
          height={35}
        />
        <CIcon
          className="c-sidebar-brand-minimized"
          name="sygnet"
          height={35}
        />
      </CSidebarBrand>
```

**HeaderLogo changes:**

```
src\containers\TheHeader.js
```

a. import the file in above file  and add new property **SRC**

```
import logos from "../assets/logo.PNG";
```

b. pass the logos to **src** in `<CIcon>` component as props

```
<CHeader withSubheader>
      <CToggler
        inHeader
        className="ml-md-3 d-lg-none"
        onClick={toggleSidebarMobile}
      />
      <CToggler
        inHeader
        className="ml-3 d-md-down-none"
        onClick={toggleSidebar}
      />
      <CHeaderBrand className="mx-auto d-lg-none" to="/">
        <CIcon name="logo" src={logos} height="48" alt="Logo" />
      </CHeaderBrand>

      <CHeaderNav className="d-md-down-none mr-auto">
        <CHeaderNavItem className="px-3">
          <CHeaderNavLink to="/dashboard">Dashboard</CHeaderNavLink>
        </CHeaderNavItem>
        <CHeaderNavItem className="px-3">
          <CHeaderNavLink to="/users">Users</CHeaderNavLink>
        </CHeaderNavItem>
        <CHeaderNavItem className="px-3">
          <CHeaderNavLink>Settings</CHeaderNavLink>
        </CHeaderNavItem>
      </CHeaderNav>

      <CHeaderNav className="px-3">
        <TheHeaderDropdownNotif />
        <TheHeaderDropdownTasks />
        <TheHeaderDropdownMssg />
        <TheHeaderDropdown />
      </CHeaderNav>

      <CSubheader className="px-3 justify-content-between">
        <CBreadcrumbRouter
          className="border-0 c-subheader-nav m-0 px-0 px-md-3"
          routes={routes}
        />
        <div className="d-md-down-none mfe-2 c-subheader-nav">
          <CLink className="c-subheader-nav-link" href="#">
            <CIcon name="cil-speech" alt="Settings" />
          </CLink>
          <CLink
            className="c-subheader-nav-link"
            aria-current="page"
            to="/dashboard"
          >
            <CIcon name="cil-graph" alt="Dashboard" />
            &nbsp;Dashboard
          </CLink>
          <CLink className="c-subheader-nav-link" href="#">
            <CIcon name="cil-settings" alt="Settings" />
            &nbsp;Settings
          </CLink>
        </div>
      </CSubheader>
    </CHeader>
```